# Is it worth bothering writing Cloudformation if Terraform exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, terraform

Sometimes CloudFormation can be too "complicated".

Which cases should CloudFormation win over Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sometimes Terraform can be too complicated too ;)*

Plenty reasons why you'd want to use *CloudFormation* instead:

1. Whether it's complicated or not depends on one's experience. CFN doesn't feel complicated to *me*.
2. It's AWS native tool, specifically developed for deploying AWS services.
3. Often has a better support for less common services.
4. AWS Support can help with CFN issues. They are not that likely to help with TF issues.
5. AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) is built on CFN.
6. Native integration with other AWS tools like *CodeDeploy*.
7. All resources belonging to the CFN stack are easily identifiable.

Ever since *CloudFormation* introduced *Change Sets* a few years ago you've got the ability to check what's going to be updated before actually updating it. That used to be the main advantage of Terraform, but now CFN offers that as well so to rephrase your question - *Why bother with Terraform?*

Hope that helps :)

Comment: > Why bother with Terraform?. 
Because Whether it's complicated or not depends on one's experience. ;)  very good answer, btw